# The requested resource does not support http method 'GET' in vb.net web api

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am working on Web API 2 in vb.net and I am getting issue with GET method.
First of all I am able able to put `HttpGet` or `AcceptVerbs` on either class or action method

I don't have `Routeconfig` because I created Web API 2 employ template project.

Here my `WebApiConfig` file

```
Public Module WebApiConfig
    Public Sub Register(ByVal config As HttpConfiguration)
        ' Web API configuration and services

        ' Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name:="DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
        )

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(New MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"))
    End Sub
End Module
```

and api controller class

```
Public Class HomeController
    Inherits ApiController

    ' GET api/values
    'Public Function GetValues() As IEnumerable(Of String)
    '    Return New String() { "value1", "value2" }
    'End Function


    ' GET api/values/5

    Public Function ConcatValues(ByVal param1 As String,ByVal param2 As String) As String
        Return "value"
    End Function

End Class
```

but When I run url : `http://localhost:43021/api/home/ConcatValues?param1=1&param2=2`

I am getting error :

> {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method
>   'GET'."}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `<HttpGet()>` attribute to the action so that the convention based routing that you configured knows to associate the action with a `GET` request. Normally the convention inspects the action's name like `GetConcatValues` to determine by convention that it is a `GET` request. Since the example action is not employing that convention that the next option is to attach `<HttpGet()>` attribute to the action definition.

```
' GET api/home/concatvalues?param1=1&param2=2
<System.Web.Http.HttpGet()>
Public Function ConcatValues(ByVal param1 As String,ByVal param2 As String) As String
    Return "value"
End Function
```